# Currying/ Piping a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, currying, ramda.js

I am currently using the [Ramda library](https://ramdajs.com/docs/) to construct new functions.
Here is a snippet of my code

```
function auth(operand) {
  if (operand.prevResult.pass && operand.req.authenticated) {
    return operand;
  } else {
    operand.prevResult.pass = false;
    return operand;
  }
}

function validate(operand) {
  if (operand.prevResult.pass && operand.req.validated) {
    return operand;
  } else {
    operand.prevResult.pass = false;
    return operand;
  }
}

function postHandle(operand) {
  if (operand.prevResult.pass){
    operand.res.send();
  } else {
    console.log('some error occured')
  }

}

const doPost = R.pipe(auth, validate, postHandle);
//const doGet = R.pipe(auth, validate, getHandle);
//const doPatch ...etc

const req = {authenticated: true, validated: true};
const res = {send: () => {console.log('sent')}};
doPost({req, res, prevResult: {pass: true}});
```

The goal was to be able to create `doPost`, `doGet`, `doPatch` etcs using some shared methods, like authentication/validations.

However, the best function I can find is R.pipe in Ramda. That does this

`(((a, b, …, n) → o), (o → p), …, (x → y), (y → z)) → ((a, b, …, n) → z)`

It only allows me to pass in one argument in the constructed function (eg. doPost, doGet). Thus, the last line `doPost({req, res, prevResult: {pass: true}});`

I was hoping there is a way for me to pass in three parameters. So I can do `doPost(req, res, {pass: true})` at the last. And also each functions signatures will look much nicer that way, like `function auth(req, res, prevResult)`, `function validate(req, res, prevResult)`, `function postHandle(req, res, prevResult)`

Comment: if readability is what you are looking for why don't you destructure? function auth({req, res,  prevResult})  you wouldn't see much diff anyway?

Answer (score 0):

[R.pipe](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe): all functions except the first function will accept only one argument.

We can overcome this by using curry function [R.curry](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry).

Generally, curry function will return a function until it gets all the arguments mentioned in the function signature.

Create the curried version of auth, validate and postHandle as mentioned below.
I hope this will solve your problem.

```
const R = require('ramda');

const isPrevResultPass = R.propEq('pass', true);
const isAuthenticated = R.propEq('authenticated', true);
const isValidated = R.propEq('validated', true);
const updatePrevResultPass = R.assoc('pass');

const auth = R.curry((req, res, prevResult) => {
    if (isPrevResultPass(prevResult) && isAuthenticated(req))
        return prevResult;
    return updatePrevResultPass(false, prevResult)
});

const validate = R.curry((req, res, prevResult) => {
    if (isPrevResultPass(prevResult) && isValidated(req))
        return prevResult;
    return updatePrevResultPass(false, prevResult);
});

const postHandle = R.curry((req, res, prevResult) => {
    if (R.not(isPrevResultPass(prevResult)))
        console.log('some error occured')
    res.send();
});


const req = {authenticated: true, validated: true};
const res = {send: () => {console.log('sent')}};
const prevResult = { pass: true };

const doPost = R.pipe(auth(req, res), validate(req, res), postHandle(req, res));
doPost(prevResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pipe multiple values through the composition of functions, you need the ability to return multiple values from the individual functions.

One way to achieve this is using an object like you have (though echoing Shyam's comment to destructure the arguments to assist with readability).

Another way to transfer multiple values between functions in a series of composed functions is by continuation passing style, where a provided callback is expected to receive the multiple results.

```js
const multiPipe = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight(
    (pipe, next) => (...args) => next(...args)(pipe))

const fn = multiPipe(
  (a, b) => k => k(a * 2, b * 3),
  (a, b) => k => k(a - 5, b - 2)
)

fn(1, 2)((a, b) => console.log(a, b))
```

An interesting ability you gain from the continuation passing style is that you can also short-circuit the pipeline to prevent calling the remaining functions by returning a result without calling the provided continuation.

```js
const multiPipe = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight(
    (pipe, next) => (...args) => next(...args)(pipe))

const auth = (req, res) => next =>
  req.authenticated
    ? next(req, res)
    : console.log('authentication failed')

const validate = (req, res) => next =>
  req.validated
    ? next(req, res)
    : console.log('validation failed')

const postHandle = (req, res) => next =>
  res.send()

const doPost = (req, res) =>
  multiPipe(auth, validate, postHandle)(req, res)()

const req = { authenticated: true, validated: true }
const res = { send: () => console.log('sent') }

doPost(req, res)
```